# Is it possible for Kivy to use two keyboards on different widgets at the same time?I

Tags: python, keyboard, kivy, multi-user

I want my Kivy app to have two users using one computer with two keyboards. The users' keyboards will be permanently focused on text inputs that they use to interact with the edit zone. I'm having trouble figuring out if this is even possible. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: This is an interesting question, I suspect the answer is no right now, since (as far as I know) kivy doesn't expose any differences between keyboards even if its backend can distinguish between them internally. I might be wrong if one of the arguments to on_key_down does vary between keyboards, you could try testing that.

Comment: This bothers me because I remember seeing a way to get a list of all the attached keyboards and thought I could do it that way but now I can't find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed possible, though not directly supported in Kivy. The software I work on uses many peripherals which emulate keyboards, such as barcode scanners and magnetic stripe readers, and each input stream is handled separately.

You can use [python-evdev](http://python-evdev.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to grab input devices individually. For each device, spawn a thread to read from the device and append its input to a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

Finally, poll the queues using [`Clock.schedule_interval`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.ClockBase.schedule_interval) with a timeout of 0 (to poll on every frame), pop items from the queue and use them to dispatch `on_key_down` and `on_key_up` events for the desired `TextInput`.

Comment: I can work with that, though not in Kivy it's the most correct answer so far. Thanks!